# interface property cannot be initialize the date value

Tags: javascript, typescript

I have typescript for the following code in interface and class initialization. The date value cannot initialize in an interface, but the class I can initialize why? Is any difference for the class and interface declaration? How do I rewrite the interface initialization code?

interface initialization is shown below

```
export interface ChatMessage {
  $key? : string;
  email? : string;
  timeSent? : Date = new Date(); //showing error here
}
```

class initialization is shown below

```
export class ChatMessage {
    $key? : string;
    email? : string;
    timeSent? : Date = new Date();
}
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Typescript interfaces are useful to describe objects but don't get compiled to javascript code and thus initializing anything in an interface won't work.

For example, you can use interfaces to ensure an object has certain properties and methods.

```
export class SecretMessage implements ChatMessage {
  $key: string = '#@(Aad*$*a__adkj32-';
  email: string;
  timesent: Date = new Date();
}
```

and as type information

```
function sendMessage(message: ChatMessage) {
    ...
}
```

Comment: okay, then how to rewrite this |timeSent? : Date = new Date();|

Comment: timesent?: Date;

Comment: okay thanks, then outside i have to initialize this.date = new Date(); right?